# How can I install an application from a .pkg without admin password?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, install

I'm trying to install the "Unity Web Player" so that I can play this game I've been waiting for for a while. The installer is a .pkg package installer which I can't use because I do not have admin access (long story). Is there a way to get the application out of the package and install it manually in my own folders?

Comment: Sorry, back to the Admin, did you try to regain it ?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to extract the main .app file from the .pkg using "Pacifist", downloaded from http://www.charlessoft.com/

Depending on what system settings are updated (or, if any global libraries or frameworks are installed) by the installer, this process may or may not work completely.